# FPGA: possible to use PC as I/O?

Tags: fpga, uart, vga

I'm a beginner in FPGAs and I would like to implement a basic CPU with a simple VGA display. If I have a FPGA that has USB-UART could I use my own PC monitor as a display? What about sending input data using my PC's keyboard?

Comment: It looks as if you've snowed yourself in, I will sprinkle some obviousness over you. There are webcams and software that shows the webcam video on your screen. So now you know that at least it's possible and maybe even a part of the USB standard. I have no idea if it is a part of the standard because I'm not Ale..chenski, the USB expert.  But maybe google can help you, now that you know that it is possible and very very common.

Comment: I found your first sentence a little impolite. Is not very common. I did google it but all the implementations used a VGA port attached to the FPGA. This is very very common. What I was looking for as an answer is something like user2913869 answer. Now I know it is not trivial and given my shortage of time I can't implement it.

Comment: @JoãoPedro - the larger problem with Harry's comment is that it has nothing practically to do with your question at all.

Answer (score 2):

USB-UART is an easy way to use your PC's keyboard to type keys and have it be received by your FPGA. You could use a terminal program such as putty or teraterm to generate the serial commands as you type. The USB-UART could also be used to send text data from your FPGA to be printed onto your PC's computer monitor (it would appear as text in the same terminal program). This may suffice if all you want to see is some feedback status messages.

If you want something more than text, such as graphics, one option would be to send a data packet over the USB-UART to be received by a custom software program running on your PC that would then draw graphical indicators as appropriate for the data provided in the data packet. This may not be beginner friendly unless you're already familiar with writing software for your PC.

If you are talking about direct VGA graphics over USB-UART, in theory that is possible, though you will probably have to make large sacrifices in frame rate, pixel resolution, color bitwidth, etc. However, it's definitely not something for a FPGA beginner.

Answer (score 0):

An FPGA development kit might be a good start. One that includes FPGA generated VGA is the Nios® II Embedded Evaluation Kit, Cyclone® III. You can Google it under that description. It's obsolete but still a valuable learning tool. I see some on eBay for less than $250.  There are youtube videos and the Wiki's "Beginners Corner" to help you learn. Learning VGA, though obsolete, is a good foundation to advance to HDMI (also obsolete) and then display port which should be here for a while.

This kit has everything from VGA out, to Ethernet, to a built-in touch screen display but doesn't have a USB input. However, it does have a serial port that you can use with a USB to Serial adaptor that NewEgg has for $1.49.

[image: Here is the I/O on it]

[image: This is how it comes with the display/touch screen]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm a little out of budget, but I gave up on the idea of using USB-UART I'm going to look for a cheap FPGA with VGA port, hopefully I can find it.